# Как получить значение из словаря, не зная имени ключа?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как получить значение из словаря, не зная имени ключа?
Есть словарь:

```
{'goto': [{'aliases': ['goto', 'gt', 'g']}]}
```

Задача:
Получить значение aliases не зная ключа (в данном случае goto)

В конечном счёте должно вернуть

```
['goto', 'gt', 'g']
```

Answer (score 0):

Я понял как это можно реализовать!

```
r = {'goto': [{'aliases': ['goto', 'gt', 'g']}]}

for a in r.values():
    print(a[0]["aliases"])
```

Comment: а у вас только один ключ первого порядка может быть? а если их несколько будет?